# How long do I wait after a failed lift?

Tags: deadlifts

I just failed a 455lb dead lift, tried to down scale to a 405lb which I've been able to pull 5 of previously and failed at that too.  How long do I rest prior to reattempting a previous max (405lb at 5 reps) and then reattempt the 455 level lift? Is it a week? or more? or less?

Comment: I'm sure that's not what you're doing, but as it's phrased like now, it sounds like you're trying to increase your lift by 50lbs. Might want to reformulate to make it clearer.

Comment: Longer than you did, probably like 3-5 minutes after a max rep attempt...

Comment: No - I ramped up to 455 my prior RM was 435, so I tried to move up 20

Comment: You failed an attempt? That is enough for today. Do assistance and finish the workout.

Comment: @ssteinberg - that was it for the day, believe me!  My questions is, do I wait a week, month, etc. prior to reattempting the lift?

Comment: You should be fine by the next time you should deadlift according to your program. If you feel like you need a deload, then deload.

Comment: A failed attempt is about as taxing as a maximal single, that is it. You definitely shouldn't need a month to recover.

Comment: It should be ok to continue the next week. Just remember to deload every  6 -8 weeks with a 9 to 14 day rest. Be easy on that spine and your joints is my personal advice.  Unless youre competing, take some breaks to build up your 1rm deadlift by strengthening the muscles themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you're following a regular weightlifting plan, you're likely weightlifting every other day. As a result, you should simply resume on your next workout day. 
 
Since your most successful lift was 435 lbs, you can start with 440 or 445 lbs. This way, the increment isn't too large to throw your body into a panic  or lose your self-confidence. 
 
Just ease yourself into it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Overtraining (or whatever name is suitable here) is a gradual process. If you abuse your body for an extended period of time (too much lifting and/or too little rest), you need an extended period of time to recover. As far as I have seen, mostly is used something like 1-4 weeks.

You should also consider what you will do in this time - easy deadlifting could be fine or doing something completely different (less destructive) may be better in various cases. The time and level of deload should really depend on how you get in the failing mode.

**Kind note:** IMHO if you are not experienced professional, I would guess you should never fail - at any cost. Training near your limit produces improvement, testing the limit produces failure.

I**n case of in-training rest between re-attempts**, please see the following chart taken from  (https://www.strongfirst.com/patience-of-strength/ - not the original source):[image: recover time]

(minutes on the X-axis, strength in % in Y-axis - note that 13-20 minutes it is possible to produce higher output - for this given case - it could be different for DL 1 rep max)

Comment: The question wasn't about overtraining (a chronic condition), it was about a single instance of training to failure. The lifter is merely fatigued from a maximal effort, and the amount of rest they need will be on the order of minutes, not weeks.

Comment: @DavidScarlett Please read the question and the comments below.

Comment: @DavidScarlett However I still upade the answer to reflect your note.